# Event click after append a template in Es6

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm using templating in es6 to reuse my HTML elements.

My Template inside a template.js:

```
const checkbox = (id, name) => { 
    return `
        <div class="checkbox-group">
            <input class="checkbox-input-hidden" type="checkbox" name="index[]" value="${id}">
            <a href="#" class="form-field-input checkbox-custom-field">
                <span class="checkbox-label">${name}</span>
                <span class="icon-check"></span>
            </a>
        </div>`;
};

export { checkbox };
```

Now, I have another js that is responsible for the view and it has a method for rendering the checkbox:

```
renderCheckbox (data) {
    for(var i in data) {
        this.checkboxContainer.append(
            checkbox(
                data[i].id, 
                data[i].name
            )
        );
    }
}
```

How can I assign a click for these elements that I'm appending to the DOM?

Comment: I'm not sure if using a framework like Angular or React.js is on the table, but that might be very helpful to these kind of things. If not, you should bind an event listener after having added the checkbox html to the dom, what can turn out to be dirty.

Comment: Are you using jQuery for the append()?

Comment: jorgonor, for this, I can't use a framework, it's for a test =)
@webbm, yes. I'm using jQuery to append.

Comment: Is the problem, that right now the click event handler isn't being executed on the dynamically added elements? In that case, learn about [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). If not, you can probably ignore this comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create a DOM element by passing the HTML string to `$`, then assign an event listener to it, and then append it to the container.

```js
$(checkbox(data[i].id, data[i].name))
  .click(() => {
    // ...
  })
  .appendTo(this.checkboxContainer);
```

By the way, you can simplify your loop by changing it to [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and using [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
renderCheckbox (data) {
  for (const {id, name} of data) {
    $(checkbox(id, name))
      .click(() => {
        // ...
      })
      .appendTo(this.checkboxContainer);
  }
}
```